# Struct variable

Tags: c, struct, var

When we have :

```
struct node {
    char...
    int....
    struct node *....
}

typedef struct node Node;
```

and then we have a function like this:

```
int function(Node f){...}
```

What is this `f` ?

Comment: `f` is a variable of type `Node`, which is essentially same as the type `struct node`.

Comment: is this like f is a struct node variable?

Comment: Yes, it is.....

Comment: More struct related terminology can be found _[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_(C_programming_language))_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the statement
`typedef struct node Node;` 
you are giving alias name of `struct node` as `Node` by using `typedef`.

So in the definition of `function()`

`int function(Node f){...}`

`f` is nothing but variable of `struct node` type.

Also you can see the `typedef` declaration and meanings here http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/typedef

Answer (score 2):

`f` is an input argument of the type `Node`. The type `Node` is synonym of the type `struct node`.

Comment: _alias_ is probably a better choice over _synonym_ for describing what `Node` is.